# Controlling the input data in php

Tags: php, validation, email

I am getting started with PHP and i've been given a task where I have to basically send e-mails in code. The part of getting the different parts of the e-mails is already done, but now I want to be sure that the given e-mail address is actually an e-mail address.

Question: How can I validate the data inside a string in PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Email addresses are a bit of a pain to validate.  `x@com` could actually be an email address.  (It's not, at least not globally, because `com` has no MX record.  But unless you're checking domains, you don't really know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use regex, use the [validation filters](http://www.php.net//manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) that's what they are built for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Preg Match](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$regexp = "/^[_a-z0-9-A-Z]+(\.[_a-z0-9-A-Z]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/";
if(!preg_match($regexp, $email)){
   $flag = false;
}else{
   $flag = true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't match `test.test@test.test.test.berlin` for example.

Comment: yes.. then what will be the valid and accurate regexp for email?

Comment: @Ronak: It's too big to go decently into an answer, assuming you want to explain it as well.  :P  Reason #4 why using a regex for this is not all that great an idea.

Comment: For reference: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ (the code's Ruby, but the idea is universal.  :P)